# exceptions thrown in an assignment

Tags: c#

I'm trying to complete an assignment that reads a .txt file and populates the fields, and displays them.

The problem uses 2 classes,

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq`
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment2
{
    internal class Tweet
    {
        private static int Current_ID = 0;
        public string From { get; }
        public string To { get; }
        public string Body { get; }
        public string Tag { get; }
        public string Id { get; }
        public Tweet(string from, string to, string body, string tag)
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
            Body = body;

            Tag = tag;
            Id = (Current_ID).ToString();

            Current_ID++;
        }

        public Tweet(string from, string to, string body, string tag, string id)
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
            Body = body;
            Tag = tag;
            Id = id;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string body = Body.Length > 40 ? Body.Substring(0, 37) + "..." : Body;
            return $"From: {From} To: {To} Body: {Body} Tag: {Tag} ID: {Id}";
        }

        public static Tweet Parse(string line)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
           // Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", parts)); test file output
            return new Tweet(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the next class:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment2
{
    internal class TweetManager
    {
        private static List<Tweet> Tweets = new List<Tweet>();
        private static string filename = "Assignment_02_TweetFile.txt";

        static TweetManager()
        {
            Tweets = new List<Tweet>();
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                do
                {
                    Tweets.Add(Tweet.Parse(line));
                } while (lines != null);
            }

        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            return $"Loaded {Tweets.Count} tweets from file {filename}";
        }

        public static void ShowAll()
        {
            foreach (Tweet tweet in Tweets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tweet.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm throwing an exception when running the parse method. The value of the txt file is around 20 or so lines of text as such:

```
Raptors Drake   Obama   Go Raptors! Go! 10001
```

with a tag, a to and from, the body, and the ID.

This is my output:

```
Raptors, Drake, Obama, Go Raptors! Go! 10001
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Assignment2.TweetManager' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Assignment2.Tweet.Parse(String line) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Assignment2\Assignment2\Class1.cs:line 64
   at Assignment2.TweetManager..cctor() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Assignment2\Assignment2\Class2.cs:line 21
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Assignment2.TweetManager.Initialize() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Assignment2\Assignment2\Class2.cs:line 30
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Assignment2\Assignment2\Program.cs:line 3
```

I need help to help this compile the list properly and show the data from the file. I am pulling 1 line from the .txt and throwing an error.

Comment: you hard coded the indexes for `parts` without checking that you got 5 parts back from split

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance and [edit] post to remove all code unrelated to the question and inline the data as constants in the code. Looks like you need a string constant and inlined version of `Tweet Parse(string line)` and nothing else.

Comment: Also while editing the post please provide meaningful title - "exception thrown in assignment" reads as if some `var x = 123;` assignment statement is failing (as "my homework broken" should not be used as a title).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more information to the `split`, such as:

```cs
line.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r', '\n' })
```

> in case you don't have any issues using the split for line breaks.

The error occurs in the `Tweet` class in the `Parse` method, when the text line is split into parts using the tab character `('\t')` in the `Split` function, because there is no `parts[1]`, `parts[2]`, etc.